# I'm trying to make an array print itself in c

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int table [100];

int main (void)
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        i = table [i];
        printf("%i\n", table[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make an array that stores 0 to table[0], 1 to table [1] and so forth and then prints it's own value.

Right now the code outputs 0's.

Comment: What values did you expect an untouched array to contain?  Hint:  Since its global, it is implicitly initialized to all zeros.  You probably want to initialize the array to the desired values before printing it.

Comment: You need to go back to your textbook or tutorial and review how assignments work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have your assignment backwards - you need to assign `i` to `table[i]`, not the other way round like you currently have:

```
table[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int table [100];

int main (void)
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        table [i] = i;
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
}
```

There you go. With nothing in the array and the iterator being reset every loop, it won't even print all hundred zeroes, just 0#0 and 0#1 forever. Now. Alternatively...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int table [] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
    41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
    61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,
    81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99};

int main (void)
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", table[i]);
    }
}
```